# Anonymous function with no curly braces and no argument labels?

Tags: swift, lambda, anonymous-function, shorthand

I saw some code on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52083874/2652785) that seems to create an anonymous function (closure expression) with some unusual syntax:

```
let plus: (Int, Int) -> Int = (+)
```

I understand the left side—that it's declaring a constant of type `(Int, Int) -> Int` (a function that takes two Integers and returns an Integer). But what is `(+)`? How can it declare a function without curly brackets, and how does it refer to the two arguments when there are no argument labels of any kind?

The function takes two arguments, adds them together, and returns the result. If I replace the `+` operator with a different one (say a `*`), the operation changes. So is it some kind of shorthand for `{$0 + $1}`? If so, what is the logic behind this shorthand?

Comment: I'm not even sure if "explain why" questions should be asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @kelin, most questions are of the 'explain why this doesn't work' or 'explain how I can accomplish this' nature. While this might solve an immediate need, the larger benefit is that knowledge is added to the tool-box—knowledge that makes one a better programmer and can be used again and again. That's why I asked the question—because I saw something in your code that I thought I might be able to learn from and possibly employ in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is no shorthand.

`plus` is a variable of type `(Int, Int) -> Int`. You can assign it any object that is of this type (or any of its subtypes). A literal lambda closure is certainly of this type, but actually a named function or method would also do. And that is exactly what is happening here.

It is assigning the operator method object named `+` to the variable.

This is mentioned sort-of implicitly in the [*Closures* chapter of the language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID101):

> ## Operator Methods
>
> There’s actually an even *shorter* way to write the closure expression above. Swift’s `String` type defines its string-specific implementation of the greater-than operator (`>`) as a method that has two parameters of type `String`, and returns a value of type `Bool`. This exactly matches the method type needed by the `sorted(by:)` method. Therefore, you can simply pass in the greater-than operator, and Swift will infer that you want to use its string-specific implementation:
>
> ```
> reversedNames = names.sorted(by: >)
> ```

So, what the code is doing is assigning the *Operator Method `+`* to the variable `plus`. `+` is simply the name of the function assigned to the variable. No magic shorthand involved.

Would you be surprised to see this?

```
let plus: (Int, Int) -> Int = foo
```

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation Jörg. I've done a little bit of Ruby coding, so I'm familiar with `+` being a method name. It just didn't occur to me that this odd looking `(+)` could be the same kind of thing in Swift. In Ruby, the mechanics are clear when you write `1.+(2)` and get 3—essentially `+` is an instance method of the Integer class. The above quote kind of implies that `+` is a method of Swift's Integer type, but neither of the following work (with or without brackets): `1.(+)(2)` or `Int.(+)(1, 2)`. I notice however that `(+)(1, 2)` does work. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, Swift doesn't let you refer to the function as `Int.+` or `Int.(+)`.  Members accessed with `.` notation have to begin with a letter or `_`.  The operator methods are special in that they use special symbols, but then the compiler expects you to use them inline `3 + 4`.  `(+)(3, 4)` works because as we mentioned before `(+)` does specify a function when the types are specified (or can be inferred as in this case).

Answer (score 2):

`+` is an `infix` operator and a *function name* in Swift.  There are many such functions defined on many types (it is overloaded).

You can define `+` for your own custom type.  For example:

```
struct Foo {
    var value: Int

    static func +(_ lhs: Foo, _ rhs: Foo) -> Foo {
        return Foo(value: lhs.value + rhs.value)
    }
}

var f1 = Foo(value: 5)
var f2 = Foo(value: 3)


let f3 = f1 + f2
print(f3.value) // 8
```

---

This works:

```
let plus: (Int, Int) -> Int = (+)
```

because the signature of the `+` function has been fully specified, so Swift is able to identify the correct `+` function.

And if we want to assign our new `+` function to `plus`:

```
let plus: (Foo, Foo) -> Foo = (+)
```

---

It's really no different than this:

```
func add(_ a: Int, _ b: Double) -> Double {
    return Double(a) + b
}

let plus: (Int, Double) -> Double = add

print(plus(3, 4.2))  // 7.2
```

---

> So why the parentheses?  Why specify `(+)` instead of just `+`?

`+` is also a unary operator in Swift.

For example, you can say:

```
let x = +5
```

So just trying to say:

```
let plus: (Int, Int) -> Int = +
```

confuses the compiler because it is treating the `+` as a unary prefix operator and it is expecting the `+` to be followed by something else such as `5`.  By surrounding it with parentheses, the Swift compiler then stops trying to parse `+` as a unary operator and treats is just as its function name.  Even if `+` weren't a unary prefix operator, Swift would still be expecting values on either side of the `+`, so the parentheses tell Swift that you aren't providing any inputs to the function, but just want the function itself.

You can refer to the `+` function without the parentheses in situations where it isn't ambiguous.  For example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
let sum = arr.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: Ahhh... the detective at his finest. :') Always a pleasure reading your answers. :'D I don't even know why i bother answering when i know that you'll come around sooner or later and deliver. _sigh_

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation vacawama. (See also my comment on Jörg's answer.)

Answer (score 2):

`(+)` by itself is an operator method. You can declare your own operator like this:

```
precedencegroup CompositionPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: AssignmentPrecedence
}

infix operator •: CompositionPrecedence

func •(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
```

Usage will be the same:

```
var closure: (Int, Int) -> Int = (•)
print("\(closure(1, 2))")
```

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer Bohdan. So really, I was asking the wrong question! (not an anonymous function at all)